# How to invoke Func with without type arguments?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

Please note, my logic is way to complicated, I have simplified everything to focus on this problem.

I have dictionary of Functions, which I have to invoke, but Function takes type T as an input argument, which is derived type, I don't have access and it can be anything at runtime. How do I invoke it?

I get following error,

```
Unable to cast object of type 
 'System.Func`2[DerivedClass,System.String]' to type    
 'System.Func`2[BaseClass,System.String]'.
```

Alternatives that I have tried and I already know about, I am looking for better performance then the following alternatives.

1. Using Dynamic
2. Recreating Expression Tree and then dynamically compile and execute

Both options are very expensive, I need simpler approach.

**This is not question about why I am getting this compiler error, or should I need to redesign my application, when I already said I have two alternatives of calling Func, I am looking for third simpler alternative if exists**

How do I invoke `Func<DerivedClass,String>` without having access to DerivedClass? I have an object with me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        object input = new DerivedClass();

        Func<BaseClass, string> f = null;

        Func<DerivedClass, string> a = s => s.ToString();

        object obj = a;

        // ERROR
        f = (Func<BaseClass, string>)obj;

        Console.WriteLine(f(input));

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}


public class BaseClass {
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Base Class";
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Derived Class";
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "i do have access" mean in your question?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have written I don't have access to the type, my code is part of generic library, which is used inside another project. So at runtime, I will have any function, I just need to invoke it.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do here doesn't really make sense. Say you have a class A, and two classes B and C that inherit from it.

If you were able to do what you say here then taking a function `Func<B, string>` and casting it into a `Func<A, string>` would mean that you get a function that can also take an instance of C as a parameter since C also inherits from A.

In fact, you could take it even further and say that since everything inherits from object, you can just cast any function to `Func<object, string>` and then pass in anything you want as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get rid of delegates for a second and think of this in terms of the methods that they are abstracting away.  Consider the following `Foo` method:

```
public static void Foo(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + 2);
}
```

Now we have another method `Bar`.  It accepts an `object`.  We want to call `Foo` on the parameter.

```
public static void Bar(object o)
{
    Foo(o);
}
```

Of course, this won't work.  We have no way of knowing that the object provided is in fact an `int`.

This generally means one of two things:

1. You don't actually want to do this; you have no way of knowing that the more general parameter is in fact going to be an instance of the correct more derived parameter; you should re-design your application.
2. You know something that the compiler doesn't, and while this constraint cannot be verified by the compiler to be correct, it will in fact be valid at runtime for whatever reason.  Since you know it won't fail, you can use a cast to inform the compiler of this, and defer the type check until runtime.

If you happen to be in that second position here, and not the first, you can add the cast not by casting the delegate, but rather by creating a new method (possibly through a lambda) that performs the cast on the parameter and then calls the other delegate:

```
Func<DerivedClass, string> derivedSelector = derived => derived.ToString();

Func<BaseClass, string> baseSelector = s => derivedSelector((DerivedClass)s);
```